# Should I commit my dist folder that is a mirror structure of my src folder to git?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, git, vercel

It's my first time building a server with typescript (using node/expres). My question is. after compiling the typescript, it spits out a mirror structure of my typescript files, which should i commit to git repository. The confusion is:

1. when i deploy to vercel from github,  which one is vercel going to run ?
2. if i exclude the src folder, then how can my team get the source code of the typescript files when i make changes. ?

This is my git ignore, i added the dist folder, but i think it's wrong, please correct me.

```
#
dist/

# dependencies
node_modules/

# debug
npm-debug.*
yarn-debug.*
yarn-error.*

# macOS
.DS_Store
*.pem

# local env files
.env*.local

# typescript
*.tsbuildinfo
```

Comment: You should commit your source code, ie your src file. Ideally, building it anywhere should give you the same contents in dist, so it's not required to add it to git.

Comment: alright, thanks a lot, so it's right to add the dist/ folder in the .gitignore, yea ?